# How to cause a screen transition when an SKSpriteNode is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am building an iOS application using the spritekit framework, and I am trying to cause the screen to transition over to the next scene when the user taps the "start" button. I am able to get the screen to transition, and load the next scene, but it happens when the user taps ANYWHERE on the screen.I only want this to occur when the user taps the "start" spritenode. I created the start button using SKSpriteNode, and I named it startButton, using the name property.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
SKAction *doNothing = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:0 duration:0];

if (startButton != nil)
{
    [startButton runAction:doNothing completion:^{
        SKScene *gamescene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:0.0];
        [self.view presentScene:gamescene transition:transition];
    }];
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(startButton != nil){ }
```

try using this in the touchesBegan method

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if([node.name isEqualTo:@"startButton"]){
  //start scene
}
```

Make sure that you set the name of the start button (label or sprite) like this

```
start.name = @"startButton";
```

EDIT:

Dont use

```
[startButton runAction:doNothing completion:^{
   ....
}
```

Instead, just transition right away

```
if([node.name isEqualTo:@"startButton"]){
  SKScene *gamescene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
  SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:0.0];
  [self.view presentScene:gamescene transition:transition];
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried inserting the code as you said, but now when I click it wont transition to the next scene (nothing happens). Could it be because I created the SKSpriteNode for the startButton using the '@property' and '@synthesize' syntax? and I was sure to name the startbutton using the .name property exactly how you noted above

Comment: Ahh i figured out my mistake it was a syntax error! Thank you!